# Setting environment variables before the execution of the pyiron wrapper on remote cluster

Tags: pyiron

I use a jobfile for SLURM in ~/pyiron/resources/queues/, which looks roughly like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --output=time.out
#SBATCH --job-name={{job_name}}
#SBATCH --workdir={{working_directory}}
#SBATCH --get-user-env=L
#SBATCH --partition=cpu

module load some_python_module
export PYTHONPATH=path/to/lib:$PYTHONPATH

echo {{command}}
```

As you can see, I need to load a module to access the correct python version before calling "python -m pyiron.base.job.wrappercmd ..." and I also want to set the PYTHONPATH variable.

Setting the environment directly in the SLURM jobfile is of course working, but it seems very inconvenient, because I need a new jobfile under ~/pyiron/resources/queues/ whenever I want to run a calculation with a slightly different environment. Ideally, I would like to be able to adjust the environment directly in the Jupyter notebook. Something like an {{environment}} block in the above jobile, which can be configured via Jupyter, seems to a nice solution.
As far as I can tell, this is impossible with the current version of pyiron and pysqa. Is there a similar solution available?

As an alternative, I could also imagine to store the above jobfile close to the Jupyter notebook. This would also ease the reproducibility for my colleagues. Is there an option to define a specific file to be used as a jinja2-template for the jobile?

I could achieve my intended setup by writing a temporary jobfile under ~/pyiron/resources/queues/ via Jupyter before running the pyiron job, but this feels like quite a hacky solution.

Thank you very much,

Florian

Comment: Is the module and the python path job specific or required for pyiron in general? 

Typically we use the `.bash_rc` for pyiron specific configurations and then set the same environment variables in the job using `--get-user-env=L`. For job specific configuration files you can add the module or the python path to the resource files: https://github.com/pyiron/pyiron-resources/blob/master/lammps/bin/run_lammps_2020.03.03.sh

Comment: The module and the python path are required for pyiron. I would like to select a specific python installation (with the correct pyiron version etc.) using the module. The change in the python path is only required for a specific pyiron-project, which is why I want to keep it out of global configuration files such as the .bashrc.

Comment: So you have a central pyiron version and in addition you want to use a secondary pyiron version via a module and a PYTHONPATH. I have to admit this configuration is not yet officially supported. But by using `--get-user-env=L` we basically transfer all environment variables from the current environment to the job when submitting to the queue. So if you set an environment variable after login, then start jupyter and submit a job using pyiron the job should still be able to access the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the example in a bit more detail:

I create a notebook named: `reading.ipynb` with the following content:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output("echo ${My_SPECIAL_VAR}", shell=True)
```

This reads the environment variable `My_SPECIAL_VAR`.

I can now submit this job using a second jupyter notebook:

```
import os
os.environ["My_SPECIAL_VAR"] = "SoSpecial"
from pyiron import Project
pr = Project("envjob")
job = pr.create_job(pr.job_type.ScriptJob, "script")
job.script_path = "readenv.ipynb"
job.server.queue = "cm"
job.run()
```

In this case I first set the environment variable and then submit a script job, the script job is able to read the corresponding environment variable as it is forwarded using the `--get-user-env=L` option. So you should be able to define the environment in the jupyter notebook which you use to submit the calculation.